# how to download a selfhosted gradle plugin

Tags: github, gradle, gradle-plugin

I have a gradle plugin that i have uploaded to github package. When it try to use the plugin in a project i got the following error: Plugin [id: 'my-plugin', version: '0.0.1'] was not found in any of the following sources.

How do i use a plugin that is published at github package?

The repository in settings.gradle looked like this:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
        maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
        maven {
            name = "GitHubPackages"
            url = "https://maven.pkg.github.com/..."
            credentials {
                username = "USER"
                password =  "PWD"
            }
        }
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
```

Comment: How have you configured the Plugin ID? In your plugin project's build config there should be a [`gradlePlugin {}` configuration block](https://docs.gradle.org/8.0/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugin_markers).

Comment: It should be set. The plugin does work when i use localMaven.

Comment: Okay, that's good. In the GitHub Packages can you see both your plugin and the Plugin Marker Artifact? Have both been uploaded correctly? Do they both have the same version? Does the Marker have the coordinates formatted as `plugin.id:plugin.id.gradle.plugin:plugin.version`?

Comment: a *.module, *.pom and *.jar file was uploaded. the jar file contains the plugin. files looks pretty the same as are stored on mavenlocal (exepct maven local generates sources and javadoc jar)

Comment: @aSemy now it works. As you mentioned the plugin marker artifact wasn't published. I didn't publish all artifacts. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-gradle-registry), GitHub Packages also has a maven repository, which is what you should use to pull your dependencies

Comment: that's what am using but to pull the gradle plugin does not work from there.

Comment: In your question, you used `https://github.com/...` as the URL for your maven repository, which, according to the docs, is wrong, which makes sense, because that's where the CODE is hosted, but not the ARTIFACTS. Instead, you should be using `https://maven.pkg.github.com/USER/REPOSITORY` as the URI

Comment: I tried it with maven.pkg.... before and it didn't worked. Where does the url has to point to that the plugin can be picked up?

Comment: Good question, I'd guess it's the user and repository that you published the plugin under